# How to declare variable for common color in style.css like style.sass

Tags: css, sass

//style.sass

```
$common-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $common-color;
}
```

can I do the similar in css? because I am not using .sass for my project.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you too, as I understand your question:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 1):

```
:root {
    --maincolor: red;
    --mainfont: Arial;
}

body {
   color: var(--maincolor);
   font: var(--mainfont);
{
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as below

```
:root {
  --common-color: #333;
}

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: var(--common-color);
}
```

Here `:root` is the scope of the variable

More information can be found in the link -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3 you're able to use variables by declaring them with `--name-of-variable` and access them with `var(--name-of-variable)`. Your example would look like:

```css
:root {
  --common-color: #333;
  --font-stack: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  font: 100% var(--font-stack);
  color: var(--common-color);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties for more information about scoping and fallbacks.